# Dependency failing: Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version but isn't being resolved to that version

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

I am building an ionic app and i don't want to do changes in `app.properties` of platform folder or any folder in the platform as it will also affect while working for CI-CD so I want to fix it without doing any changes in platform folder in ionic app.

Error: In the project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. The behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

**app.properties:**

```
target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-android-support-gradle-release/citizen-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker/citizen-ignorelinterrors.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.3=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.40.0
cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:support-v4:25.+
cordova.system.library.5=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.9=com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+
cordova.system.library.10=com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.4.0@aar
cordova.system.library.11=com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3
cordova.system.library.12=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+
cordova.system.library.13=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker/citizen-androidtarget.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.4=cordova-support-google-services/citizen-build.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.5=phonegap-plugin-multidex/citizen-multidex.gradle
cordova.system.library.14=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
cordova.system.library.15=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+
cordova.system.library.16=com.android.support:support-v13:27.+
cordova.system.library.17=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar
cordova.system.library.18=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2
```

the exact error is as below:

```
In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity@15.0.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@17.3.2
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@15.0.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@16.+

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dependency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your build.gradle file.
```

can anyone please help with this issue? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to mix `play-services` dependency version. Always use same version

```
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.12=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
```

Comment: I am not mixing those versions, I am using different plugins and those plugins are adding dependencies with different versions. 



though I am able to fix this issue by adding the `googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true` in bottom platform/android/app/build.gradle file but I don't want to touch anything in platform folder as it is affecting things while making build on ci cd server.